# Finite Additivity of Outer Measure Implies Separate Sets

Tags: measure-theory

Here's the problem: if A,B subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda ^*(A\cup B)=\lambda ^*(A)+\lambda ^*(B)<\infty$ then $\exists E,F $ measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy: $A\subset E$, $B\subset F$ and $\lambda (E\cap F)=0$.\
I think I have to prove that the two sets are somehow separated. I was able to show the reverse path, but I am having trouble with this direction. I tried using the $\varepsilon$ characterization of the infimum using the definition of the outer measure to create a sum smaller than $\lambda ^*(A)$ and another one for $\lambda ^*(B)$ adding them together and then using the given equality: for $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $(I_n),(J_n)$ open covers of A and B such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)<\lambda ^*(A)+\varepsilon/2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(J_n)<\lambda ^*(B)+\varepsilon /2$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(J_n)<\lambda ^*(A\cup B)+\varepsilon$. Moreover, $(I_n\cup J_n)$ is an open covering of $A\cup B$ so we have $\lambda ^*(A\cup B)<\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n\cup J_n)$. Should I create a sequence of coverings using $\varepsilon=1/k$? I believe the goal is to create two open coverings of A and B that satisfy $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(J_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n\cup J_n)$.  ($\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure, $\lambda ^*$ is the outer lebesgue measure and $l$ is the length). Thank you in advance.

Comment: $A=[0,1]$, $B=\Bbb R$ gives a counterexample. The missing assumption is...

Comment: I apologize for the inaccuracy, I fixed it.

Comment: Why not simply revise the statement at the top (as I did just now) instead of leaving the false statement there and then fixing it in the last line?

Comment: Hint: You can take $E$ and $F$ to be countable intersections of open sets. Each of the open sets comes from an open cover of something such that something...